# Does the question mean she will do all 3 sports on one day in the week, or if she will do all 3 sports in a week, but individually on different days

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, word-problem, combinatorics-on-words

Jo is going on an 8-day activity holiday. Each day she can choose one of the water sports: kayaking or sailing, or land-based sports. She never does different water sports on consecutive days. She also wants to try all three options on at least one day of her holiday. How many different schedules are possible

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.  Just referring to the question in the header:  I think it's clear that there are three sports:  $K, S, L$ and that she must choose one a day.  She can not choose $KK, KS, SK$ or $SS$ on successive days but otherwise she can choose whatever she likes.  How many $8$ day schedules are possible given that each of $K,S,L$ must appear at least once?

Comment: @lulu KK and SS seem to be allowed while KS or SK are not

Comment: Related but not quite the same: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399037/bmo1-2013-solving-a-recurrence-relation

Comment: @Henry  Absolutely right.  It's just $KS$ and $SK$ that are forbidden.

Comment: Sorry if I’m not making much sense. What I mean is in the question it says she wants to try all 3 activities on at least one day of her holiday. I’m probs over complicating this, but I’m interpreting this as she wants to do all 3 activities on one individual day, essentially creating another alternative to the 3 activities already above. I’ve got an answer doing the method you have mentioned previous to asking this question,mI just wanted to make sure I’m not being paranoid over the details

Comment: @SuissSuuee: Each day she does just one of the three.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put. She has 8 slots (marked as X below):

X X X X X X X X

1st condition: She must do all sports for at least 1 day (a complicated way of saying she has to do all sports at least once):

2nd condition: She can't do different consecutive water sports (a complicated way of saying she can't do kayaking or sailing in a row (KS or SK). So example solutions are as below:

K L S L K L K L

This fits both conditions